# Firebase statistics

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have an Android Application that is not on Google play. I have implemented Firebase to send messages from my server to the app.
It works well but on the Firebase console I do not see statistics.
I would like to know if my account is within limits once I go live with this update. I see that there are some statistics on Google play, but my app is not on Google play.

What are the exact limits for Firebase messages and how does it work?

-Simultaneous connections - 100 (if there are more, the messages will not be sent?) - the connections seem to close fast on Android

-GB stored 1 GB - in case the message is not sent?

-GB downloaded 10 GB/month

The message is just a 2words text so I do not think I could reach 1GB

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually you can see the details of downloaded and stored data on Firebase under Usage tab.

[image]

**Simultaneous connections = 100 (if there are more, the messages will not be sent?) - the connections seem to close fast on Android**

> Firebase Cloud Messaging has no limits for connections or usage. It's absolutely free

**GB stored 1 GB and 10GB downloaded per month**

> This limit is for Firebase Database. FCM has no limits.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean Firebase Cloud Messaging, I've already ask firebase support, and there is no limit.

It's absolutely free and unlimited.

The limit that you mention in you question is for firebase realtime database.