# Are the firebase limits per application or per application user?

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage

First, sorry if it is the wrong place to ask it.

I could not find a suitable information in the Firebase pricing page or the faq. Indeed, I don't know how to interpret the pricing data : are the limits for the Spark plan per developper or per application user ?

I mean, for example, are the 5GB storage limit to be shared among all my application users ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 5GB storage limit is for all your applications users and not per developer.

Hope it helps.

Comment: So, there is 5GB for each user of my application : did I well understand ?

Comment: No, all your users share those 5 GB.

Comment: Thanks, I understand, so would you advice me to use Google Drive Api instead ?

Comment: No, I advice you to use Firebase. Those 5 GB are enoght for starting an app. If your app will grow fast, then i suggest you consider purchase a payed plan.

Comment: I am so likely to use Google Drive in order to prevent fast growing limits : 25$/month are too expensive for me. Even if I may not reach it. If firebase comes to be too limitfull, I plan to switch to another solution (why not Dropbox ?).

Comment: Because Firebase does not provide you only the storage, it provides `Realtime Database`, `Authentication`, `Crash Reporting` and so on. See [offical website](https://firebase.google.com/).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151284/discussion-between-loloof64-and-alex-mamo).

Answer (score 2):

To answer your question, yes the 5GB storage limit are to be shared among all you application users. Firebase limits for **Spark Plan** is lists as below:

**Simultaneous connections**

> You can have thousands and hundreds of users, and there is no limit at that.
>
> But when it comes to simultaneous connections, you can only have 100 connections(user that access your firebase database) at a time.

**Storage limit**

> You can have up to 5GB stored data in your firebase storage. The user has nothing to do with the limits of the data. The limit is for your database storage.
>
> You can also have up to 1GB downloaded data per month. This means that every time your user access your database it will downloaded the data from the firebase storage to their app.

For more information on Firebase Usage, Limits & Statistics refer to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45270305/firebase-statistics/45270334#45270334)